# KeyEventTranslations.tr shortcut setting - work/not work

Tags: front-end, keyboard

About editing KeyEventTranslations.tr

`Item[KeyEvent["q", Modifiers -> {Control}], "MoveNextWord"]` : working

`Item[KeyEvent["y", Modifiers -> {Control}], "MoveNextWord"]` : not working

For the same instruction, some combination of keys work, other combination of keys not work.

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has been used.
For Windows OS, it's `MenuItem["Re&do", "Redo", MenuKey["y", Modifiers->{"Control"}]]`.